# The lightest Windows 10 configuration possible for low-spec computer

Tags: windows-10

I've got an old PC (10+ years) that I want to use to push things on my TV, but Windows 10 is so heavy that it seems to take basically everything my computer has just to run it.

So I'm wondering: What options could I turn off/tone down so Windows 10 is at the lightest as it could be?

I've considered putting Linux on it, but I want to be able to run small games like LoL or L4D on it, and being on linux prevents me from running them.

So is there a Windows 10 configuration that is considered the lightest?

Comment: Let me be the first to say: Linux

Answer (score 2):

The lightest Windows 10 configuration is Windows 10s. You may downgrade
Windows 10 to 10s by re-installation.
Only Microsoft Store applications are allowed with this version,
so it's not a good solution for running games.

There are a few "unofficial" modifications of Windows, stripped down of
many components by secret hackers. Of course it’s illegal (equals piracy)
and you can’t know if they baked in any spyware.
If you wish to go this way, see for example
[Windows 10 Lite](https://softopc.com/windows-10-lite-free-download/),
but I don't take any responsibility.

Your other option is a small Linux distribution. You could use the WINE package
to run Windows programs (although not all of them will work).
Going this way, be ready to invest some personal time in the project.

Answer (score -1):

After trying to find really "light" OS for the old computers I have find only [Slax Linux](https://www.slax.org). *There is the problem with lack of community to find solutions you need to customize it. For example to change wallpaper is work for hours. Also it is not installable by default to HDD/SSD. But it is possible to do it.*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).